# RecyclerView Adapter + Data Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Okay so I'm trying to implement Data Binding in my recyclerview adapter, and I need help because I don't know how exactly? I'm trying to remove boilerplate code from my recyclerview adapter, that's why. Check my codes down bellow:

**custom_row(Recyclerview item layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="toDoData"
            type="com.jovanovic.stefan.tododemo.data.ToDoData" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/row_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@{toDoData.title}"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description_txt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:maxLength="160"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="@{toDoData.description}"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title_txt"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_txt" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**ToDoData**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "todo_table")
data class ToDoData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var priority: Int,
    var description: String
) : Parcelable
```

**MyAdapter(Recyclerview Adapter)**

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
       val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there. To complete your implementation, follow the following.

In your adapter, create the view holder that will support data binding.

```
class ViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: CustomRowBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(todo: ToDoData) {
            binding.todo = toDoData
            // make sure to include this so your view will be updated
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = CustomRowBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your oncreateViewHolder

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }
```

And finally onBindViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val todo = todoList[position] // this will be the list object you created
        holder.bind(todo)
    }
```

Comment: I have removed my 'MyViewHolder' and replaced it with the one you have provided. It works, thank you! :)

Comment: how the "CustomRowBinding" class generated? Please explain i am trying but couldn't find my binding class for recycleView.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try [SmartRecyclerView](https://github.com/Kunalapk/SmartRecyclerView/)

```
smartRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.smartRecyclerView)
smartRecyclerView.apply{
        initSmartRecyclerView(activity = this,smartRecyclerViewListener = smartRecyclerViewListener,isPaginated = true)
        isEnabled = false // enable/disable SwipeRefreshLayout
        setClickListener(onItemClickListener) // (optional, set 
        clickListener on recyclerview items)
        setViewAttachListener(viewAttachListener) // (optional, set viewAttachListener on recyclerview items)
        setScrollListener(recyclerViewListener) // (optional, set 
        setScrollListener on recyclerview items)
        setShimmerLayout(R.layout.item_loader) // (optional, set shimmer layout while user waits for the data to load)
     }




private val smartRecyclerViewListener:SmartRecyclerViewListener<T> = object:SmartRecyclerViewListener<T>{

        override fun getItemViewType(model: T): Int {
            return 0 //return viewType from model
        }

        override fun getViewLayout(viewType: Int): Int {
            return R.layout.item_file // on the basis of viewType return the layout you want for the recyclerview item.
        }

        override fun setListSize(size: Int) {
            //this method will be called whenever smartRecyclerView undergoes any operation.
        }

        override fun onRefresh() {
            //do something on refresh....
            smartRecyclerView.isRefreshing = false
            Toast.makeText(baseContext,"OnRefresh Called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onLoadNext() {
        // onLoadNext() will be called if isPaginated = true and user scrolls to bottom or the smartRecyclerView.
            Toast.makeText(baseContext,"OnLoadNext",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    
    
        //DiffUtils Callback functions
    
        override fun areContentsTheSame(newItem: T, oldItem: T): Boolean {
            return newItem.distance==oldItem.distance
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(newItem: T, oldItem: T): Boolean {
            return newItem.uuid==oldItem.uuid
        }

    }
```